# Connect to Rally using HTML

Tags: html, external, rally

I am trying to connect to Rally Defects using an external HTML to generate a Highcharts graph for defect tracking. Any ideas on how to connect? 
I tried to look and i found REST APIs using Java and Ruby present online.

Answer (score 1):

Patrick - are you trying to have a webpage that uses a Highcharts graph based on data pulled from Rally? - If you are trying to do this through JavaScript, you will need to use the 1.x API, and will need to use an external login key.

You can find information about the external login key at the following link:
https://prod.help.rallydev.com/loginkey

Unfortunately, as far as I know, external login is not yet supported for API 2.x, so if you want to have an information radiator /wallboard with visualizations using a JS visualization framework, you will need to grab the data using the 1.x API (or get the data server side).

Comment: After looking at the options i think i would like to make an app using the 2.0API as it has integrated highcharts support as well

Answer (score 0):

Check out the App SDK:
https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/

The App SDK makes it easy to access Rally data in an html/javascript environment.  There is even a [Rally.ui.chart.Chart](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.chart.Chart) component built on highcharts.

The following guides will probably be useful to you:

- [Getting Started](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/getting_started)
- [Developing Apps Externally](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/developing_externally)
- [Data Stores](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/data_stores)
- [Data Visualization](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/data_visualization)